# How to import Prettier's html tag for template literals in TypeScript?

Tags: prettier

I have a .ts file with tagged template literal (`html` tag as described here: https://prettier.io/blog/2020/08/24/2.1.0.html#api ), like this:

```js
const myFunction = (arg) => {
  return html`<p>
    hello ${arg}!
  </p>`;
}
```

Prettier formats the code correctly, but unfortunately after compilation it complains:

> `ReferenceError: html is not defined`.

Should I import anything or my configuration is missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Prettier doesn't provide such function, I need to create one by my own.

Ref: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11431

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I have nothing to add

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using html as a Tag for a template literal. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function and javascript wants to know where that function is. So just give it this in your program:

```
function html(x) {
    return x.raw[0];
}
```

You can learn more about [Tagged Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)